# Alternative to the Beads Task for the role of emotion in belief revision

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias, decision-making, belief

**Context**

I'm interested in understanding how emotion / affect is linked to belief revision. My supervisor suggested I use the classic beads task or something similar to it to get at this problem. Example of a beads task: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13546805.2016.1192025

**Problem**

The beads task is well suited to study jumping to conclusions and belief formation... but since it ends when you choose the jar where the beads, it does not really get at the issue of belief revision. By revision, I mean that you form one belief, then there is a reversal of sorts, and you need to adjust your belief.

**Question**

Are there alternative to the Beads Task that might be better suited to belief revision rather than formation?